# Dynamic view getting inserted with whole screen android

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app where parent layout is a scrollable view and I add a view dynamically to this parent layout using following code:

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View format = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
        ll.addView(format);
    }
```

Here is the view where I want to insert the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/backgroundf"
 android:weightSum="8"
 android:id="@+id/takeattendanceinterim">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/bLogoImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/icwhitehouse"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@null"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Class 5 Section A"
                            android:id="@+id/tClassAndSection"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textSize="20dp"/>

                        </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="07 Feb 2016"
                            android:id="@+id/tDate"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textSize="20dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/bLogOut"
                        android:src="@drawable/iclogoffsmallest"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@null"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4">
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/StudentNames"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/parent">
                        </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bMarkAllPresent"
                            android:text="All Present"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bMarkAllAbsent"
                            android:text="All Absent"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bContinueToTakeAttendance"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the view which I want to insert: student_present_absent.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundf"
    android:id="@+id/abcdef">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/student_present_absent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/bLogoImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/icwhitehouse"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/bLogOut"
                    android:src="@drawable/iclogoffsmallest"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/bLogOut1"
                    android:src="@drawable/iclogoffsmallest"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/whiteline1">
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the code inserts the whole page of student_present_absent.xml So i get full screen of student_present_absent.xml 5 times, where i just want only 70DP of layout to be repeated 5 times.

Please help.

Comment: You can solve that by changing `android:layout_height` of `id:parent` to `wrap_content`

Comment: Didnt work and I am still getting whole page.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine. Can you upload a scrennshot?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a usecase for a Listview/Recyclerview with multiple layouts.

Using google I found the following Link... I didn't test it but it looks quite good at first sight:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html

Answer (score -1):

You can add 5 view static as like below.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

 View format = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
 View format1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
 View format2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
 View format3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
 View format4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_present_absent,null);
  ll.addView(format);
  ll.addView(format1);
  ll.addView(format2);
  ll.addView(format3);
  ll.addView(format4);
```

Comment: Hi vasant, I am doing the same with for loop, but the problem is that the whole screen of format is inserted whereas i only ned part of the layout to be inserted sine most of the page is empty

Comment: so, you need to give android:visibility="gone" to parts those you dont need to show.